# Typescript compilation error in imported react node_module, even though it's excluded in tsconfig.json

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I've been having a fun time trying to see if I can't get my typescript build to ignore the node_modules (specifically React). My tsconfig.json is telling it to ignore the folder, but it is still being compiled, and I'm not sure why. I suspect maybe it's because it's being imported by a file within the included files, perhaps?

Here's an example of the error, of which there are many:

```
ERROR in /Users/rw3iss/Sites/site/src/project/public/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
(3606,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'feTile' must be of type 'SVGProps<SVGFETileElement>', but here has type 'SVGProps<SVGFETileElement>'.
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "noResolve": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./secure/node_modules/@types",
      "./public/node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [ "react" ]
  },
  "filesGlob": [
  ],
  "include": [
    "secure/src/**/*",
    "public/react_src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "public/node_modules/**/*",
    "secure/node_modules/**/*",
    "public/dist"
  ],
  "types": [ "react" ]
}
```

I'm trying to compile it with webpack/ts-loader, and my webpack config is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {

    entry: {
        app: [
            APP_DIR + '/react_src/Secure.tsx',
            APP_DIR + '/react_src/DicomViewer.tsx'
        ]
    },

    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        path: BUILD_DIR, // 'dist'
        filename: '[name].js', // 'index.js'
        //libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        modules: [ 'node_modules', 'src' ]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/, 
                include: APP_DIR,
                exclude: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                        '../public/node_modules',
                        '../node_modules'
                    ],
                loader: ['ts-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Could anyone tell me why these errors are happening, and possibly how to avoid them and other errors that might pop up in imported node_modules?

**Update:**
I removed everything under 'typeRoots' and set 'types' to []:

```
"typeRoots": [],
"types": []
```

But it's still throwing the same errors. I'm just trying to understand why...

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get my typescript build to ignore the node_modules (specifically React). My tsconfig.json is telling it to ignore the folder, but it is still being compiled, and I'm not sure why.

The error is related to the react type declarations in the `@types` directory. Even if we exclude `node_modules`, the `@types` directory is included in the compilation.

Here is some further, [relevant information from the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation... If typesRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included... If types is specified, only packages listed will be included.

Your tsconfig includes a `types` property that specifies `[ "react" ]`. Changing the `types` property to an empty array `[]` may resolve the error. Note that `types` belongs under `compilerOptions` not at the top level.

See also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11257

Comment: Hi Shaun, thanks. I did try this, to no avail. I removed everything in typeRoots, and types all together, but it's still throwing the same errors. I added this to the description above.